# Implementing a temporal table on existing large table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to implement temporal tables on an existing table that has millions of rows. When altering the table to `ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME`, it appears to lock the table. My theory is that it's checking to make sure that there are no cases where the period start is later than the period end (logically, a check constraint to that effect). My initial thought was to add a filtered index for that condition, but having comparisons between columns isn't supported there. I was able to make the alter table run faster with a non-filtered index on the period start and end times but it's still likely to be a "no-go" in production.

Are there any tricks to performing that alter table without locking the table?